# Recycler view scrolling images only one at a time

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am new to android development, i am now developing an application in which i need to have a recycler view its scroll should be disabled. i have implemented the gesture listener when i swipe up and down i need to scroll the recler view images one by one (only one at a time)

Please guide me how to do this if not in recycler view if i have some other options to perform this please suggest me i just need to scroll list of images one bye one only one at a time

If the question is not clear please let me know

Thank you

Comment: post your code mann :)

Comment: i still dont understand ur purpose, plz explain more

Comment: try with this :- https://github.com/kaelaela/VerticalViewPager

Comment: Use **Vertical ViewPager** as @Avi suggested.

Comment: If you want to scroll the images one at a time you can use the `viewpager` from the design support library (for horizontal scroll) and if you want vertical scroll use the library as @Avi mentioned(or any other with similar functionality). If you just want to snap the items on scroll use the `LinearSnapHelper` from the support library

Comment: yes i understand that view pager is a good idea but i want to have a list of items in the same page and when i scroll down i just want have the flowers to be set to a view